# Toshiba - ATI graphic card update with ATI driver

Tags: toshiba-laptop, opengl, ati-mobility-radeon, display-driver

I have Toshiba A200 and ATI Radeon HD 2600 graphic card. I need to work OpenGL 3.0 or above versions.

ATI released a driver which runs OpenGL 3.1 with my graphic card.
However when I tried to update driver from the ATI website I got this error

> ATI Catalyst Mobility cannot be downloaded due to incompatible hardware/software on your computer. Your computer does not contain a proper graphics adapter.

Do you know how to install this update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to install this update. You'll have to hope and pray and [Toshiba releases an upgraded driver.](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst119ReleaseNotes.aspx)

Given that a Radeon HD2600 is fairly old, I don't think this is going happen anytime soon

Comment: +1  Toshiba is your only real hope.